# Giving a local machine an external static IP ( can be just forwarded ports)

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding, iptables

I've planned to make one of my home machines to be a mail server I can receive mail from other people on. I have a domain name for it, and I know I need a machine with a static external IP so I have a DigitalOcean instance with an external static IP available, but my soon-to-be mail server doesn't have one - it's a typical machine behind a router behind a router and so on. I plan on making this DO instance a VPN server, connect a domain to it and connect my mail server to it through VPN, then setup port forwarding so that the mail server will have the necessary ports available. What am I missing? Are there any circumstances I don't take into account? What would the iptables rules on the instance be?

Comment: Fail2ban and the firewall ill work perfectly. But if you install iRedMail on the DO machine they will defend that **and** the mail server. If instead you install iRedMail on the mail server at home, your DO will need another layer of defense. But other than this, they will work fine no matter where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing really difficult in what you are planning, just some work.

You did not specify which kind of VPN you plan to use, so that I can only give you a generic recommendation: you must make sure that your mail server will receive always the same (private) IP address, on the other end of the tunnel (or bridge, it depends...), so you must make sure you know how to setup static IP addresses for VPN clients.

As for the mail server, I **strongly** suggest you to use [IRedMail](http://www.iredmail.org/), a fully comprehensive solution for mail servers in the Linux world which can take care of everything for you, and which will make your life, both as an installer and as an administrator, so much easier.

Now comes my question: if you have already gone thru the expense of a DO account, why not put your mail server on it, instead of keeping it at home? The advantage of this is that IRedMail comes with a firewall and `fail2ban` pre-configured, and they give you a pretty good security. If instead you put the mail server elsewhere, you will have to put the firewall and fail2ban, separately, on the DO machine.

If you decide to keep the mail server at home, you will have to port-forward some ports from the DO to the mail server. Assuming the mail server has IP address, on the VPN, 10.0.0.2, the rules you need are:

```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i etho --dport 110 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:110
  iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.0.2 --dport 110 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

This works for port 110 (dovecot's listening port), TCP connection, and assumes that the **outer** interface of your DO is called `eth0`. You will have to establish which ports you wish to leave open to the world.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I do acknowledge need for static address on the VPN, and I've already chosen IRedMail as a solution to be used =) Why won't the firewall and fail2ban work though? Is it because of some forwarding nuances? If so, I think there's a good chance that configs that IRedMail will create on the mail machine will work after being substituted as configs for firewall&fail2ban running on DO instance (with minor changes, of course).